# Javascript padStart() working correctly in alert box but not in email record in Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: javascript, whitespace, padding, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have created an action that gets values from a CRM record in which are appended in a stringbuilder.  Within the string that is being built, I need to add something to the equivalent of 10 spaces between the string as seen below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ltRecordSnsAndLocations.length; i++)
{
    if(i < ltRecordSnsAndLocations.length - 1)
    {
        injectionString += (i+1).toString() + ". " + ltRecordSnsAndLocations[i][0].toString() + String("System Location:  ").padStart(String("System Location:  ").length+10,' ') + ltRecordSnsAndLocations[i][1].toString() + "\n";
    }
```

Which seems to be working correctly seen by the output in the alert box below:

[image]

As you can see, there is the correct padding between the number bulletted values and the system location which is what I want.

As stated earlier, I created an action in CRM which inputs this string into an email record denoted by the variable `injectionString` as seen below:

[image]

However, when the workflow kicks off and the `injectionString` passed in is populated, it ignores the `padStart` as seen below:

[image]

I've been fighting with this for a while now.  Important to note that I tested in both Chrome and Edge Browsers. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see padStart in the posted code

Comment: The alert box uses plain text, it preserves the white-space. When adding the text to an HTML element, extra white-space is truncated to a single character on the view. Adding [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS rule to the element might help?

Comment: @danh it's there:  String("System Location:  ").padStart(String("System Location:  ").length+10,' ')

Comment: Sorry - I see it now. Side note: A few intermediate string variables in the loop will help with debugging and help future readers of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following blogpost provided the solution to my problem:
https://blog.hubspot.com/website/html-space

> The simplest way to add a space in HTML (besides hitting the spacebar)
> is with the non-breaking space entity, written as `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`.
> Multiple adjacent non-breaking spaces won’t be collapsed by the
> browser, letting you “force” several visible spaces between words or
> other page elements.

[image]